# Task cancellation with condition in case of positive response from server side

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task, task-parallel-library

I have three tasks like this

```
public List<CheckResponse> Check(CheckRequest request)
{ 
   var Responses = new List<CheckResponse>();
   List<Task> TaskList = new List<Task>(); 

   Task task1 = new Task(() =>
   {
      Service gatewayObject = new Service();
      var response = gatewayObject.Check();
      Responses.Add(response);
   });
   task1.Start();
   TaskList.Add(task1);

   Task task2 = new Task(() =>
   {
      Service gatewayObject = new Service();
      var response = gatewayObject.Check();
      Responses.Add(response);
   });
   task2.Start();
   TaskList.Add(task2);

   Task task3 = new Task(() =>
   {
      Service gatewayObject = new Service();
      var response = gatewayObject.Check();
      Responses.Add(response);
   });
   task3.Start();
   TaskList.Add(task3);

   Task.WaitAll(TaskList.ToArray());

   return Responses;
}
```

Each of them make request to service and can return positive result
so I want to cancel other two task if any of them return positive result.

**Service side code is not accessible for me so I can not make any changes on service side.**

Comment: you could use `Task.WaitAny(TaskList.ToArray())` and then cancel the other tasks

Comment: But result must be postive! So WaitAny isn't option. You should create cancelation token and pass it to all three task and throw it back only if result is positive!

Comment: Side note: You have a (highly likely) potential threading bug here - code inside your three tasks are each modifying `Responses`, which isn't in general a safe class for concurrent access.

Comment: Darko Maric Programer Yes you right but cancellation token can cancel task if running code work in my side so I can't stop it if gatewayObject.Check() was not finished yet.

Comment: If your `gatewayObject.Check` doesn't support cancellation (by accepting `CancellationToken` - you cannot really "cancel" anything (nor do you need to). You just need to wait for first positive response with `Task.WaitAny` (in a loop, so if task failed you do one more `Task.WaitAny` with the rest of tasks) and forget about other tasks (and don't add response to the list - you need just one response so return it from the task).

Comment: Have a single cancellation token. Pass it to all three tasks. Have any successful task cancel the other two as part of it's success.

Comment: @Evk Thanks but I have one more question related with your answer. Can I lose any task result till I check current result and run Task.WaitAny(TaskList.ToArray()) again.

Comment: e.g. something like, for each task do `task.ContinueWith((t)=>if(t.IsCompletedSuccessfully){tokenSource.Cancel();}}`

Comment: Then do WaitAny on the resulting continuation tasks.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever can you provide how to fix my code to make it safer.

Comment: @Evk Thanks a lot I have solved my problem.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks a lot I have solved my problem.